# What is distribution of ratio of two gamma function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let suppose there are two gamma function X and Y.

$$X:Gamma(10,\alpha)$$
$$Y:Gamma(10,\beta)$$

I found that if  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are same, the distribution is beta distribution.

But i like to know case when second parameter is different.

How can i found it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a paper on this topic: [Malik, 1967](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cmb/v10/cmb1967v10.0463-0465.pdf)

"Exact Distribution of the Quotient of Independent Generalized Gamma Variables"

According to [Rao and Garg, 1969](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cmb/v12/cmb1969v12.0865-0868.pdf)

"It may be called a generalization of the beta distribution of the second kind..."

Answer (score 1):

**Fact 1**. Let $X \sim \Gamma\left(n, \alpha\right)$, and let $Y = \gamma X$ for a positive constant $\gamma$, then $Y \sim X \sim \Gamma\left(n, \gamma \alpha\right)$.

**Fact 2**. Let $X \sim \Gamma\left(n, 1\right)$, $Y \sim \Gamma\left(n, 1\right)$ be independent random variables. Ratio of these variables, $Z = \frac{X}{Y}$ has [beta-prime distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution) with $\alpha=\beta=n$, and pdf
$$
    f_Z\left(z\right) = \frac{1}{\mathrm{B}\left(n, n\right)} \cdot \frac{z^{n-1}}{\left(1+z\right)^{2 n}} \cdot [ z > 0 ]
$$ 
where $[ \cdot ]$ denotes [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), and $\mathrm{B}\left(a, b\right)$ denotes [Euler's beta-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Combining these facts, for $X_a \sim \Gamma\left(n, a\right)$, $Y_b \sim \Gamma\left(n, b\right)$:
$$
   Z_{ab} = \frac{X_a}{Y_b} = \frac{a}{b} \frac{X}{Y} = \frac{a}{b} Z
$$

Comment: First time I hear about Iverson, indicative functions have been called Dirac or Kronecker for more than a 100 years, they are not English speaking but give credit where credit is due

Comment: @statquant Iverson bracket is an indicator: $x \mapsto [x \elem A]$ is a function equal to 1 whenever $x$ is a member of set $A$ and zero otherwise. As far as I know Kronecker is a special case when domain of the function is a set of integers and $A$ is one element set.